# How to upload multiple files form local directory via PowerShell to SharePoint Online?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have a lot of files in a local folder (> 5.000) which need to be uploaded to SharePoint Online through PowerShell.

How can i loop through all files within a local folder, authenticate myself againt SharePoint Online and upload the files to a document library through PowerShell?

Comment: This may help get you started: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/762291/upload-files-to-library-in-sharepoint-using-powers

Comment: Hi, please write some code and we'll help you debug it.